# How to exclude some of the folders while creating zip file through maven

Tags: maven, maven-assembly-plugin

```
<assembly xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/assembly/1.1.0"
     xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/assembl/1.1.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/assembly-1.1.0.xsd">
    <id>bin</id>
    <baseDirectory>/</baseDirectory>
    <formats>
      <format>zip</format>
    </formats>
    <fileSets>
      <fileSet>
         <directory>src/main</directory>
         <outputDirectory>/</outputDirectory>
         <excludes>
            <exclude>src/main/dml</exclude>
         </excludes>
      </fileSet>
    </fileSets>
    </assembly>
```

This is my assemble.xml. **src/main** contains several folders.  I want to **exclude** some folders, like **src/main/dml**, but it is not being excluded.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

Use this `excludes` to match the `dml` folder and its contents. Be sure to use a path relative to `<directory>src/main</directory>`

```
  <excludes>
            <exclude>dml/**</exclude>
  </excludes>
```