# Mave-assembly-plugin: customize descriptor to exclude a folder

Tags: maven, maven-3, maven-plugin, maven-assembly-plugin

I have the following directory structure:

```
MyProject/
   - temp/
     - cat_A/
         - tmp/
         - file_A
     - cat_B/
         - tmp/
         - file_B
```

I am using [maven-assembly-plugin](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/). I want to create a tar.gz file with the content to be like following:

```
output/
  - cat_A/
    - file_A
  - cat_B/
    - file_B
```

I tried to make a custom descriptor as following:

```
<assembly …>
   <id>my-result</id>
  <formats>
    <format>tar.gz</format>
  </formats>
  <fileSets>
    <fileSet>
      <directory>${project.baseDir}/temp</directory>
      <outputDirectory>output</outputDirectory>

      <!-- tried to exclude tmp/ folder-->

        <excludes>
            <exclude>${project.baseDir}/temp/cat_A/tmp</exclude>
            <exclude>${project.baseDir}/temp/cat_B/tmp</exclude>
        </excludes>

    </fileSet>
  </fileSets>
</assembly>
```

But the final output still contains the tmp/ folder.

How to exclude the `tmp/` folder and achieve the result I want?

Comment: Ah...excludes as the [docs](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/assembly.html#class_fileSet) describes?

Comment: Ah...in fileSets there is not `<unpackOptions>`...just remote it. Take a look into the docs.

Comment: @khmarbaise, please check my update again. I tried with exclude, but the tmp/ folders are still included in the final output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because it's a directory you have to change your exclusion to:

```
    <excludes>
        <exclude>/cat_A/tmp/**</exclude>
        <exclude>/cat_B/tmp/**</exclude>
    </excludes>
```

Update: *Without `${project.baseDir}/temp` because it's relative to your directory*

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16214086/how-to-exclude-some-of-the-folders-while-creating-zip-file-through-maven) and [that](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/advanced-descriptor-topics.html) provide further information.

Comment: lol. Sry seems I am having a bad day. Corrected my answer. You're absolutely right...

Comment: Thanks, but now the output is empty. I need to check for a while

Comment: It seems it excludes the cat_A/tmp/** including the parent directory. That's why I got empty output

Comment: Hmm maybe another minor failure: try `<exclude>cat_A/tmp/**</exclude>` without `/` at the beginning

Comment: tried, still, empty output :( , also tried `<exclude>cat_A/tmp</exclude>`

Comment: I think the last version without `/` at the beginning is right and something is wrong with `<directory>${project.baseDir}/temp</directory>`. Maybe because it can't resolve the variable?! It's just a feeling because I played a bit around with the directory and got different outputs on the console but somehow it doesn't build my zip...